# Firebase logs "undefined" on console when it should not

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using **firebase 10.9.2** (Latest version)

I use the onValue function to go through the data in my live database. For some reason, it always logs (and is set to) *undefined*.

Due to how fast firebase evolves, I can not find a fix for this current issue.
**Please tell me what can I do with the code so that it stops returning undefined.**

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.8/firebase-app.js";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBU21edukO9sxUR13wYy6yYW9ZYK5ax4tM",
    authDomain: "team-seas-demo.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://team-seas-demo-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app",
    projectId: "team-seas-demo",
    storageBucket: "team-seas-demo.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "864989587728",
    appId: "1:864989587728:web:7eda88906cd9a7fe659d95"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

import {getDatabase, ref, set, child, update, remove, onValue}
from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.8/firebase-database.js"; 

var db = getDatabase(app);

onValue(ref(db, "Groups/"), function (snapshot){
    const data = snapshot.val(); 
    console.log(data); //This part works, but returns the whole object

    console.log(data.GroupName) //This part returns undefined...
});
```

P.S: Yes, my rules on read are set to `true`

This is how my database looks:
[Image of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjmMP.png)

Comment: What are you expecting other than what you observe?  We can't see the data in your database, so we have no way of knowing if this is actually correct or what to change in order to meet your expectation.  Please edit the question to provide more details.  I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DougStevenson I have edited the post, you can see the data now. I already linked it earlier in my full project, there is no issue on that.

Comment: You have a node in between Groups and GroupName.  You will need to know its name and account for that in the snapshot you get. Just accessing GroupName by itself will not work, as you can see.

Comment: @DougStevenson Right!!!! Thank you so much! You have no idea how much I have been beating my head over this issue

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use the onSnapshot() function
See an example here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: They're using the realtime database, not firestore.

Comment: Yeah, I need the realtime database anywyas @NicholasTower. However, I am trying the other solution a guy commented on my question. If that does not work or I can't figure it out, I will revert back to this onSnapshot()